# Why does openFeatureForm crash QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm working on a Qgis plugin with python,

I'm creating a feature and I show a feature form to edit the attributes. But after the `openFeatureForm` function call the program crash and close

```
line = QgsFeature()
line.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(transformedLine))
pr = parcoursLayer.dataProvider()
pr.addFeatures([line])
qgis.utils.iface.openFeatureForm(parcoursLayer,line)
```

[image: this is the message after crash]

Comment: Do you get an error message or stack trace?

Comment: What kind of layer is parcoursLayer? OGR? Memory?

Comment: @Branco, i didn't get any message

Comment: @underdark, it's not a Memory layer, it's the current layer

Answer (score 1):

we are facing the same issue here. 
It seems related to a bug in PyQt4.

See preloadForm method comment here for a workaround :

http://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html

and here the issue raised to QT / Pyqt 4 by NathanW:

http://forum.qt.io/topic/26562/crash-calling-c-method-using-quiloader-from-pyqt4

Answer (score 0):

Before to set geometry of 'transformedLine' try out to print it. This object should have a form similar (if it is projected in meters) to this (for one feature):

```
[(366179,4.46968e+06), (357711,4.44966e+06), (363870,4.43041e+06), (382100,4.41947e+06), (396590,4.41078e+06)]
```

A list of **QgsPoint**.

The another strange thing is in:

```
pr.addFeatures([line])
```

You are passing a list where it is expected a feature but, the method 'addFeatures' does not exist in **QgsDataProvider**. It is in **QgsVectorLayer**. Normally it would be:

```
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(transformedLine))
feat.setAttributes([1]) #one feature with id = 1; several features in a loop
your_layer.addFeature(feat, True)
```

Comment: I show the transformedLine and it's a liste of QgsPoint, and I did what you said, but I have the same problem